# Employee health insurance before vs after tax deduction

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance

The employee insurance I am being offered gives a choice deduction being taken out before or after tax.  Which of these choices would result in overall more money saved?

Cost of insurance is ~ $60 a month.

Comment: They're offering you an after tax deduction on your health insurance? That choice is typically offered on long term disability or life insurance, not health/medical insurance.

Answer (score 4):

I've only seen this option on disability insurance, so correct me if that is not accurate.

The difference is whether the *benefit* is taxable. If you buy the insurance with pre-tax dollars, then any benefit you get would be considered income and subject to income tax.

If you buy it with after-tax dollars, then the benefit would not be taxable.

So which to choose is not obvious - pre-tax insurance is "cheaper" upfront, but will reduce your net benefits since you'll have to pay tax on them.  But if you never *need* disability, then you're paying less overall. Post-tax costs more upfront, but your benefits won't be taxable.

If you can afford the post-tax option, it's probably the best choice *if you ever need it*. It's the point of insurance, after all, to pay for something hoping you'll never need it...